# What's next: after successful token created for django all-auth; how to sync google calendars?

Tags: django, google-calendar-api, google-signin, django-allauth

Ok, I hope I don't get too beat up here for this question as it is kind of complex. At least in my view, with what I know so far. So the details first: 
I built a nice app with django that brings in event data for users, utilizes that data for many things (not relevant to this question) but one of the things is that it syncs these events to the users Google calendar.  I made the google app within the developer console, and it uses the provided credentials.json file to allow users to authenticate the app, thus creating individual user token.json files per user, then I have another script (not within django, just a custom python file) that runs from a cron job to automatically sync/ update the calendar info from the database to the google calendars.

Now, the new problem is having this work without my help. IE: a new user logs in and creates a profile, then if they should choose to sync to their Google calendars I have to be there, running the authentication process from my personal server. So I did that, by moving the whole app to a hosted platform and brought it up to speed in production mode.

Users can create a profile, using django-allauth it works to make an initial user account where they can  fill in the rest of the profile. It does populate the token string for their account, but here is where I'm stuck.

What process is there to make the token.json file OR use the existing token string (the one it saves now on the server version) to allow the system to sync the calendars? Once the token files are created, the rest of this works. I just can't get the right answers to how django-allauth will handshake with Google and do this?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: ultimately wound up using a service account with google api, and directing my users to combine the service account email (adding it as a shared user to the specific calendar) and they copy/paste the shared calendar ID in their profile on my app. All the logic now just uses this share function to sync the calendars, and it works great.